# Como incluir una imagen de carga (Loading) , ejecucion ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Codifique el siguiente codigo que uso luego de hacer un "Onsubmit" en formulario:

```
function buscar(){
    resul = document.getElementById('resultado');
    bus=document.frmbusqueda.dato.value;
    tipo=document.frmbusqueda.tipo.value;
    ajax=nuevoAjax();
    ajax.open("POST", "busqueda.php",true);
    ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (ajax.readyState==4) {
            resul.innerHTML = ajax.responseText
        }
    }
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax.send("busqueda="+bus);

}
```

Todo funciona a la perfección lo que necesito es que antes de que me de el resultado agregar una imagen de loading, en el codigo.

Alguna sugerencia u/o ayuda.

Gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dentro de la funcion `ajax` de jquery existe el metodo `beforeSend` donde puedes mostrar un div que contenga este loader que quieres mostrar

```
beforeSend: function() {
     $('#tu_loader').show();
},
```

Y en el success lo ocultas.

O tambien puedes hacer arriba del llamado del ajax la llamada a tu div que contiene el loader

```
$('#tu_loader').show();
//$.ajax({
```

Y en el `success` haces el `.hide()`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar:

```
beforeSend: function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta solución hace que muestre/oculte el id loading vinculado a un div.
En este caso siempre que sea una petición ajax o de carga normal se ejecutará y evitas tener que hacer codigo para cada situación.

> Requiere jQuery

```
        jQuery(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            jQuery('#loading').show();
        });
        jQuery(document).ajaxStop(function () {
            jQuery('#loading').hide();
        });
```